# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{xy}{2}}dxdy$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I've tried using the Jacobian matrix, but this method yielded no significant results. Another way is to turn this integral into the
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^22^n}
$$

However, I do not know how to find the exact sum of this series.

Comment: see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function

Comment: Your comment has helped me a lot. I'm going to study Spence's duties.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. ;)

Comment: Try the change of variable $u=(x+y)/2,v=(y-x)/2$

Comment: The answer should be $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln^2 2$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117340/269624) for reference. Another form of the integral is $$I=-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-\eta) d\eta}{1+\eta}$$

Comment: If you integrate with respect to one variable, then apply integration by parts you arrive at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3113395/515527

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the function to use here is 
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$$
so that your sum is given by $S=\frac12\mathrm{Li}_2(\frac12)$. To evaluate this exactly, we use the formula
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(z)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln(z)\ln(1-z)$$
and plug in $z=1/2$ to get
$$S=\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\ln^2(2)}{4}.$$